# C# insert foreign key that has same value with primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I insert my `FK_clubID` from `ClubMember` table that references `Clubs(clubID)`?

I'm using the `identity (1,1)` on `clubID` should I add the value for `FK_clubID`?

```
    public void addclubs(string clubname, DateTime established, byte[] images, string activate)
    {
        string insertSQL = "INSERT INTO Clubs(club_name,established,image,activate)" + "Values(@club,@esb,@img,@acv)";
        Connect();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@club", clubname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@esb", established);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", images);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acv", activate);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return ;
    }

    public void addclubmember(string presidentID , string viceID, string secID, string president, string vice, string sec)
    {
        string updateSQL = "INSERT INTO ClubMember(presidentID,viceID,secID,president,vice,sec) VALUES (@prs,@vice,@sec,@prsn,@vicen,@secn)";
        Connect();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prs", presidentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vice", viceID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec", secID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prsn", president);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vicen", vice);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secn", sec);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: So ClubMember has a column that is the FK id to the Club table?

Comment: @Steve yes, let's say when I register the club, my FK_clubID will be added to clubmember where FK will have the same value with the PK

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the first method to return the ClubID just inserted

```
public int addclubs(string clubname, DateTime established, byte[] images, string activate)
{
    string insertSQL = @"INSERT INTO Clubs(club_name,established,image,activate)
                         Values(@club,@esb,@img,@acv);
                         SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
    Connect();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@club", clubname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@esb", established);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", images);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acv", activate);
    int newClubID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return newClubID;
}
```

In this way you get back the last identity value inserted using your connection instance. Of course you could add it to your query that updates the members of that club changing the current query to add also this parameter for its column.

Beware that the last inserted identity in your connection could be different if there is a trigger on the club table that inserts data in other tables with identity columns

Unrelated to your current problem I have also two other advices to your code. First, try to use objects to represent Clubs and ClubMembers, it is not clear if you have just a bunch of simple variables here or if you have a more structured way to represent your data models. Second, do not use AddWithValue. This is handy but has many drawbacks both in terms of performances and in terms of reliability. See [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column in your database table of "ClubMember" named "clubID" which has a foreign key constraint with primary key from "Club" table, this is how you insert the value:

```
public void addclubmember(string presidentID , string viceID, string secID, 
string president, string vice, string sec, string clubID)
{
    string updateSQL = "INSERT INTO 
    ClubMember(presidentID,viceID,secID,president,vice,sec, clubID) VALUES 
    (@prs,@vice,@sec,@prsn,@vicen,@secn, @clubID)";
    Connect();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prs", presidentID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vice", viceID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec", secID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prsn", president);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vicen", vice);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secn", sec);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clubID", clubID);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```